# What are `$adapted$` methods I see in JMC/JFR?

Tags: scala, jvm, jit, jmc, jfr

When benchmarking some scala code using Java Flight Recorder/ Mission Control, I can see a bunch of methods that have an `$adapted$` in the name. I can think of a few possibilities for this, looking at the signature.

- Are these the same as java-8 function lambdas? i.e. that won't generate heap allocations?
- Are they specializations of generics (in scala, or templates in java)?
- Or are they some other sort of optimization?

Where can I read more about this?

Comment: This is some sort of fixtures I think. Scala compiler usually abuses with $, and may generates some additional methods, packages, etc. when you create say static object
    object Foo

Comment: Thanks for posting this question, I'm noticing `$adapted$` appears with curried functions. Have you found any other patterns with what determines this name? Useful for reflection purposes...

Answer (score 0):

This is some sort of fixtures I think. Scala compiler usually abuses with $ in class names and some java code may fail, it may generate some additional methods, packages, etc. when you create say static object

```
object Foo {
    case class Bar()
}

val bar = new Foo.Bar().getClass().getSimpleName() shouldEqual "Foo$Bar"
```

So, probably it was just generated by compiler or some other type-level-magic-macro-library